# NetworkInfo.isConnected() returns true but no connection

Tags: java, android, networking

I use gar's answer from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts) to check internet connection availability. But, I'm not sure if it works correctly. If I turn off WiFi and mobile data connection and run the application, `NetworkInfo.isConnected()` returns true when there's no connection to the internet available.

What's wrong? If I turn airplane mode on, it correctly says no connection.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27312494/3124150) answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There is sadly no way to determine if you have a internet connection with the current Android API**. You can only determine if an adapter (WiFi, 3G, LTE, etc) is connected to a router.

That said, you can implement something that pings a known domain (www.google.com)? To determine in your connection is valid, but that will take time (a second or more on a bad connection).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's very unfortunate.